# iphone - How to add text on UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to add text on uitoolbar, like Mail App when download email, there will show downloading on toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a UILabel as a subview isn't the best approach...

See this question for the best approach:

[UILabel inside a UIToolbar using IB is invisible on run, how fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946496/uilabel-inside-a-uitoolbar-using-ib-is-invisible-on-run-how-fix)

i.e. you use a UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score -4):

Just add a UILabel as subview of the UIToolbar.