# Making UIBarButtonItem act like UILabels on a UIToolbar, not dimmed and not glowing on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added a `UIBarButtonItem` to a `UIToolbar`, and made it emulate a `UILabel` as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947503/1037617).

Here is some sample code:

```
UIToolbar * toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarInitialFrame];
UIBarButtonItem * labelEmu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
[labelEmu setEnabled:NO];

/* some more buttons */

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:labelEmu, spacer, doneButton, nil]];
[container addSubview:toolBar];
```

My problem is that with `setEnabled:NO` the button is inactive but dimmed, and with `setEnabled:YES` the button is not dimmed, but glows when pressed.

How can I get this button to be not dimmed AND inactive (so it doesnt glow when pressed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the UIBarButtonItem with a custom view like this:

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 25)];
[label setText:@"Settings"];
[label sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem * labelEmu=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];
```