# Centering on a UIToolBar with a UIToolbarButton on either side

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to center some text on a UIToolBar with a button on either side, but I am having some problems.

I have the following code:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarInitialFrame];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 25)];
[label setText:@"Title"];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];   
UIBarButtonItem * labelEmu=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelAlarmAndDismissDatePicker:)];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(setAlarmAndDismissDatePicker:)];
```

So what I want is the cancel button (`cancelButton`) on the left, the title (`labelEmu`) centered in the middle, and the done button (`doneButton`) on the right. Something like this:

```
|[Cancel]    Title    [Done]|
```

I was hoping I could achieve that with this:

```
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: cancelButton, spacer, labelEmu, spacer, doneButton, nil]];
```

But unfortunately what I get is this:

```
|[Cancel]Title        [Done]|
```

After some playing about, Ive found that this line:

```
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: cancelButton, spacer, labelEmu, spacer, nil]];
```

...produces this:

```
|[Cancel]    Title          |
```

Where the title is centered, ignoring the fact that the cancel button is there. But when I do this:

```
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: spacer, labelEmu, spacer, doneButton, nil]];
```

...it produces this:

```
|        Title        [Done]|
```

Where the title is centered in the space between the far left edge and the right side of the done button. It is not ignoring the done button in the same way it ignores the cancel button.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to get what I am after? Sorry about all the naff ASCII diagrams! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"yourtitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

It might help if the UITollbar will be in charge on the label.

**EDIT**
Try adding:

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

Before adding it to the tollBar

Comment: See this post I made: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19118305/1037617 - adding a UIBarButtonItem like this results in the title glowing when pressed. I want a title that doesn't glow. Besides, my UIBarButtonItem is still controlled by the UIToolbar, it just has a custom view with a UILabel in it.

Comment: This doesnt effect the result either. I really don't think the issue here is the UILabel.

Comment: Well soory, Just trying to help here :)

Comment: didnt mean to cause offense :)

Comment: ok, sizeToFit did work. very sorry, you were right, I was wrong - it took a bit of playing about until I realized my stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

---EDITED---

After further investigation - turns out problem really was label. You have set it's width to 200.

Should be a lot less for it to autoresize correctly.

See this code:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 50)];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

[self addSubview:toolBar];

UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 25)];
[label setText:@"Title"];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
[label sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem * labelEmu=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelAlarmAndDismissDatePicker:)];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(setAlarmAndDismissDatePicker:)];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: cancelButton, spacer, labelEmu, spacer, doneButton, nil]];
```

It generated something like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, Your code works. Problem was that label width is too big - as advised by shannoga - use sizeToFit, after You set it's title value

Comment: thanks for making me realize what I was doing wrong. If I could mark you both as correct I would, but Im giving the tick to shannoga as they suggested this first. Very sorry, I know a single upvote is a small consolation, but its all I can offer :(

Comment: No problem! As long as You got Your answer, and becides - shannoga was first one to suggest it! So big thanks to You for an upvote! And good luck in further coding adventures! :)